# Is it possible to keep google from using certain text as keywords?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, ranking

For example, on my site I have a lot of flash content. But, I made sure to put plenty of keywords each meta  description for each page, a descriptive title for each page, all the alt tags for images should be filled, i used the h1 and h2 tags with some sentences using key words that describe the site...

But my problem is that I have a large TOS and Privacy policy page, and according to google webmasters it looks like its getting most of my key words from that single page. So my top keywords look like, "privacy" "policy" "liability" and stuff like that which is in no way relating to my site.

I'd really appreciate any input that might help me get the privacy policy and tos keywords off the radar so I can get relavant searches coming to the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not coming up for searches you consider relevant, it's not because you rank well for privacy and TOS searches or because those pages are large. It's because each page is judged on its own merit and your pages aren't (in Google's opinion) deserving of ranking well for those searches. Ranking well for one search phrase does not preclude a page from ranking well for other search phrases.

If you want your pages to rank well you will need to do a lot more then have good meta tags (useless for SEO), title, alt images, etc. You'll need to have good content that drives links to your pages. This is especially true if the search phrases you want to rank well for a competitive in any way.

In your case you're handicapped by using Flash for your content. Flash is not SEO friendly. Yes, Google can crawl Flash but you lose out on important SEO tools like semantic markup and internal linking. Basically you're going to need to hope that users find your flash content good and worth linking to. Maybe you can put some content on your pages that explains how they can do that for you? Anything to help that along is a good thing.

Comment: You covered the 'why' very well, i'd like to add the 'how': http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/seo-friendly-flash.shtml